# returning a dictionary from a function in node js gives undefined

Tags: node.js, undefined

I am trying a code where analyzeText function which returns a dictionary is called but it returns undefined

```
const attributeThresholds = {
        'a': 0.5,
        'b': 0.4,
        'T': 0.5,
        'S': 0.6,
        'I': 0.6,
        'F': 0.50,
      };

const requestedAttributes = {};
      for (const key in attributeThresholds) {
        requestedAttributes[key] = {};
      };

async function func1(text){
var data ={};
const res = response.data.attributeScores; //a nested dictionary


for (const k in attributeThresholds){
                  //console.log(res[k]['summaryScore']['value']>attributeThresholds[k]);
                  data[k] = res[k]['summaryScore']['value']>attributeThresholds[k];
               };
              //console.log(data);

               return data;

}
```

The console.log(data) prints

```
{
        'a': false,
        'b': true,
        'T': false,
        'S': true,
        'I': false,
        'F': true,
      }
```

But when I call the function the return value is undefined

```
try {
      
    scores = analyzeText('I hate you');
    console.log(scores);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

This code snippet prints

```
Promise { undefined }
```

I tried to debug but I am not able to as I am new to javascript

Comment: I'm guessing the func1 you defined is the analyzeText function. 
The problem is the async keyword, get rid of it and your code will work okay.
Why? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that `func1` and `analyzeText` are the same function, it can't work because you function is asynchronous.

To get the return data of your function you have to a use `then`

```
analyzeText('I like you')
.then(scores => {
    console.log(scores);
});
```

If you call `analyzeText()` in an async function you can use `await`

```
const score = await analyzeText('I like you')
console.log(scores);
```

Then: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Await: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await